# amazon s3 upload image in to perticular folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have created a bucket with the name "testbucket". so when ever I upload images it is saving in that bucket,but I have created a folder on that bucket with the name "images".so when ever I upload a image it will save in to images folder.please help.Here is my code.

```
Map<String, Object> amazonCtx = FastMap.newInstance();

        amazonCtx.put("bucketName", "testbucketvamsi");
        amazonCtx.put("keyName", fileName);
        amazonCtx.put("uploadFileName", imgPath);
```

The file name is dynamic. so what ever the file name is there it should save in that images folder which I have created.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below for the uploading to sub folder in S3 bucket.

Map amazonCtx = FastMap.newInstance();

```
    amazonCtx.put("bucketName", "testbucketvamsi");
    amazonCtx.put("keyName", "folder/${filename}");
    amazonCtx.put("uploadFileName", imgPath);
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me with the below code  amazonCtx.put("keyName", "images/"+fileName);